# Android network is not being added to Wifi List

Tags: java, android

I'm using a function to add a network to the wifi list :

```
 public void connecttowifi(String networkSSID, String networkPass) {
        try {
            WifiConfiguration conf = new WifiConfiguration();
            conf.SSID = "\"" + networkSSID + "\"";
            conf.preSharedKey = "\""+ networkPass +"\"";
            conf.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.NONE);
            WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
            wifiManager.addNetwork(conf);
            List<WifiConfiguration> list = wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks();
            for( WifiConfiguration i : list ) {
                if(i.SSID != null && i.SSID.equals("\"" + networkSSID + "\"")) {
                    wifiManager.disconnect();
                    wifiManager.enableNetwork(i.networkId, true);
                    wifiManager.reconnect();

                    break;
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.d("Wifi exception is",ex.toString());
        }
    }
```

In MainActivity.java I wrote:

```
 connecttowifi("333","333");
```

The network is not being added and no exception is found, any help ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can Log in the loop

print SSID of all ConfiguredNetworks

and I guess this is the problem:

```
if(i.SSID != null && i.SSID.equals("\"" + networkSSID + "\""))
```

take off  "\" to below

```
if(i.SSID != null && i.SSID.equals(networkSSID))
```

hope this help!!

Answer (score 0):

```
conf.SSID = "\"" + networkSSID + "\"";
conf.preSharedKey = "\""+ networkPass +"\"";
```

networkSSID and networkPass  are instance of String,don't need to escape

```
conf.SSID =  networkSSID ;
conf.preSharedKey = networkPass;
```